# TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers' . any solution for the same?

Tags: langchain

I am running from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain it is showing TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers' . any solution for the same?

from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain

TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers' .